# Add columns in complex data type nested data frame

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame which has simple type and complex structure like struct, array of struct, array of array of struct. I have an expected schema(StructType as root). I need to mold the data frame with respect to schema. If columns are missing which are not in data frame, we need to add those columns to DF with default value.

For Example:

**Expected Schema :-**

```
root
 - struct
   - a: String
   - b: Int
   - c: array of struct
     - e: String
     - f: String
```

**DataFrame Schema :-**

```
root
 - struct
   - a: String
   - b: Int
   - c: array of String
```

How to do it recursively at each level of element using spark?

Here is what I am doing in the code.

```
   // Function to add missing columns recursively
def addMissingColumns(df1: DataFrame, df2: DataFrame, currentPath: String = ""): DataFrame = {
    val df1Schema = df1.schema
    val df2Schema = df2.schema

    val missingColumns = df1Schema.fields.filterNot { field1 =>
        df2Schema.fields.exists { field2 =>
            field1.name == field2.name && field1.dataType == field2.dataType
        }
    }

    val dfWithMissingColumns = missingColumns.foldLeft(df2) { (accDF, field) =>
        val colName = currentPath + field.name
        val dataType = field.dataType

        dataType match {
            case _: StructType =>
                val updatedDF = if (accDF.columns.contains(colName)) {
                    val missingCols = addMissingColumns(df1.selectExpr(s"$colName.*"), accDF.selectExpr(s"$colName.*"), colName + ".")
                    missingCols
                } else {
                    accDF.withColumn(colName, lit(null).cast(dataType)) // You can cast to the appropriate data type
                }
                updatedDF
            case _ =>
                // Handle non-struct types by adding them with null values if missing
                val updatedDF = if (accDF.columns.contains(colName)) {
                    accDF
                } else {
                    accDF.withColumn(field.name, lit(null).cast(dataType))
                }
                updatedDF
        }
    }
    dfWithMissingColumns.printSchema()
    dfWithMissingColumns.show()
    dfWithMissingColumns
}


def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
        .appName("YourAppName")
        .master("local[1]") // Use all available CPU cores
        .getOrCreate()

    // Sample DataFrames
    val df1 = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
        (1, "Alice", Array(1, 2), (10, "New York", ("dddd","ggg"))),
        (2, "Bob", Array(3, 4), (20, "San Francisco", ("ddd","ggg")))
    )).toDF("id", "name", "numbers", "location")
    df1.printSchema()

    val df2 = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
        (1, "Alice", Array(1, 2), (10, "New York 2")),
        (2, "Bob", Array(3, 4), (20, "San Francisco 2")),
        (3, "Ankur", Array(3, 4), (20, "Netherlands 2"))
    )).toDF("id", "name", "numbers", "location")

    df2.printSchema()

    addMissingColumns(df1, df2, "").printSchema()
}
```

The issue with the code is it is returning only location column. Here is the output schema -

```
 root
 |-- _1: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- location._3: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can convert `df2` to `json` data using `to_json` function & then convert back to columns by passing schema of `df1` in `from_json` function. By default this approach add missing columns with default values.

Logic - `df2.select(from_json(to_json(struct($"*")), df1.schema).as("data")).select($"data.*")`

Please check below & It is quit faster than recursive logic.. :)

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

    val df1 = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
        (1, "Alice", Array(1, 2), (10, "New York", ("dddd","ggg"))),
        (2, "Bob", Array(3, 4), (20, "San Francisco", ("ddd","ggg")))
    )).toDF("id", "name", "numbers", "location")
```

```
scala> df1.show(false)
+---+-----+-------+-------------------------------+
|id |name |numbers|location                       |
+---+-----+-------+-------------------------------+
|1  |Alice|[1, 2] |{10, New York, {dddd, ggg}}    |
|2  |Bob  |[3, 4] |{20, San Francisco, {ddd, ggg}}|
+---+-----+-------+-------------------------------+
```

```
scala> df1.printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- numbers: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)
 |-- location: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _1: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _3: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
```

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val df2 = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
        (1, "Alice", Array(1, 2), (10, "New York 2")),
        (2, "Bob", Array(3, 4), (20, "San Francisco 2")),
        (3, "Ankur", Array(3, 4), (20, "Netherlands 2"))
    )).toDF("id", "name", "numbers", "location")
```

```
scala> df2.printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- numbers: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)
 |-- location: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _1: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
```

```
scala> df2.show(false)
+---+-----+-------+---------------------+
|id |name |numbers|location             |
+---+-----+-------+---------------------+
|1  |Alice|[1, 2] |{10, New York 2}     |
|2  |Bob  |[3, 4] |{20, San Francisco 2}|
|3  |Ankur|[3, 4] |{20, Netherlands 2}  |
+---+-----+-------+---------------------+
```

```
scala> val updatedDF = df2.select(
  from_json(
    to_json(
      struct($"*")
    ), 
    df1.schema
  )
  .as("data")
)
.select($"data.*")
```

```
scala> updatedDF.printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- numbers: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
 |-- location: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _1: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _3: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
```

```
scala> updatedDF.show(false)
+---+-----+-------+---------------------------+
|id |name |numbers|location                   |
+---+-----+-------+---------------------------+
|1  |Alice|[1, 2] |{10, New York 2, null}     |
|2  |Bob  |[3, 4] |{20, San Francisco 2, null}|
|3  |Ankur|[3, 4] |{20, Netherlands 2, null}  |
+---+-----+-------+---------------------------+
```

Comment: Works pretty well. Thanks for providing solution. Did not really think  on this direction

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add new columns to a nested column with ArrayType of StructType, you can do it as Scala code below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{IntegerType, LongType, StringType, TimestampType, StructType, ArrayType}


val elem_struct_recomposed = new StructType().add("e", StringType).add("f", StringType)

val newDF = df.withColumn("c", lit(null).cast(ArrayType(elem_struct_recomposed)))
```

Comment: I am looking for more generic function which accept a data frame and expectedSchema as parameter and return the updatedDF with all missing columns

Comment: If you want to read your data with a specific schema, you need to force it when reading data files. but if you want handle some specific and complex situations like the one you mentioned in your question, you need to write a function for each one of them. @Ankur